# Using SVN in Xcode 4 with MacOSX Lion (10.7)

Tags: svn, xcode4, osx-lion

my problem is this: I should upload a project on SVN server to put it under version control. I successfully created a new repository, inserted url, username and password, but when I click on the "root" directory, the spinner rotate infinitely. My Mac configuration is Lion and Xcode 4.3.2

[image]

If I create the same repository on another Mac with Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard, work's perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode isn't great with SVN. I'd suggest you get http://versionsapp.com/ to manage connections to your repository / setup / etc. You can then use Xcode just for commits / updates. I've had several times when I've run into XCode not seeing commits / updates / projects as being under version control with svn and Versions helps sort it all out.